# Extracting counts of a variable grouped at 2 levels

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have weather data tagged by year, month and day. Here is some of the data:

```
Date         MinT     Year   Month
1976-01-01   1.1      1976   1
1976-01-02   0.3      1976   1
1976-01-03   1.3      1976   1
```

The data run is 1976:2016 for all months. Call this TestData.

I can group and subset as follows (it is very clunky but that is because I have been trying to test each step)

```
temp1 <- TestData  %>%
  group_by(Year) 
temp2 <- temp1 %>%
  subset(between(Month, 1, 3)) 
temp3 <- temp2
v1 <- replace(temp3$minT, temp3$minT >-2.0,0)  ### replaces data above the threshold 
temp3["v1"] <- v1 
index1 <- with(temp3, tapply(X = v1, INDEX = Year, FUN = sum)) ##       sums the month  1-3-2 degree values
index2 <- with(temp3, tapply(X = v1, INDEX = Year, FUN = length)) ## counts the number of items in each year for the selected period.
```

`index2` gives me a count of the days in each month. I can use `index1` and 2 to create index of 'weather for the month'.

What I would like is to be able to get a count of all of the days below -2 (or whatever) and so get an index of comparable severity for each month.

The `v1` assignment is necessary because if I use `rle` to count instances, some months will have zero instances and they drop from the final tally meaning the compiled table of indices against `minT`, `year` and `month` has index vectors of different lengths which R doesn't like. I have tried `rle` as the FUN in the `index2` assignment but that would not let me reach the day counts. The same was true for using a range value with length in that assignment (`index3`) as well.

Short of generating a mini table for each year, I am stuck. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I guess `summarise` is the function you are looking for. Something like this (different data, same principle):

```
library(latticeExtra)

threshold <- 40

SeatacWeather %>%
  group_by(year, month) %>%
  filter(min.temp < threshold) %>%
  summarise(days_below_threshold = n())
```

Comment: trying this on my data I get an error "no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"

Comment: You could try `TestData$Year <- factor(TestData$Year)`. Otherwise we probably need more information.

Comment: Thank you! I thought of this in the middle of last night before I read this. What I did was declare temp1 a data frame. That allowed group_by to work! The threshold filter segment then produced the days. Once again - Thank You!